# DAX Filter function parameter from a measure

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, selectedvalue

I'm trying to set up a custom filter using DAX in Power BI.
The idea is to use a parameter/value extracted from a Slicer.
So far, I was able to get the selected value from the Slicer, but I was not able to use it in a filter.
The filter expression works perfectly when I manually type the parameter "value", I mean:

`FILTER(BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD, BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[ORIG_GRUPO]="5DSL" || BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[DEST_GRUPO]="5DSL")`

Works just fine, but:

`FILTER(BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD, BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[ORIG_GRUPO]=[Measure] || BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[DEST_GRUPO]=[Measure])`

doesn't work.

The measure is working fine, as I created a "dummy" card to test it.
The measure itself is calculated by a DAX SELECTEDVALUE function:

`Measure = SELECTEDVALUE(Tabela[GRUPO], "TODOS")`

Can someone help me at this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Get the measure value in a VAR in this DAX and use inside to it, as below.

VAR _SelectedValue = [Measure]
RETURN
FILTER(BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD, BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[ORIG_GRUPO]=_SelectedValue  || BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[DEST_GRUPO]=_SelectedValue )

I believe the selection is single select not multiple.

Comment: As far as I understood, DAX is not able to handle the measure as a "value". When I use a constant/string, the filter works as intended, but when I try to associate the measure to the parameter, it doesn't work.
That works:
FILTRO = 
VAR PAR = "5DSL"
RETURN
FILTER(BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD, BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[ORIG_GRUPO]=PAR || BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[DEST_GRUPO]=PAR)

That doesn't
FILTRO = 
VAR PAR = [GRPSEL]
--VAR PAR = "5DSL"
RETURN
FILTER(BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD, BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[ORIG_GRUPO]=PAR || BI_PRD_MAPA_TRD[DEST_GRUPO]=PAR)

[GRPSEL] is a measure that uses DAX's selectvalues function.